# Fortran 90/95 OpenMP reduction with an array (sum)

Tags: loops, fortran, openmp, nested-loops, fortran90

I'm working on adding some OpenMP directives to a large set of fairly expensive nested loops.  I believe I need to use a reduction clause with my directive since the operations on the array on not necessarily independent.  However, when attempting to add the reduction directive my application core dumps (but does compile).  I'm using IBM's XL Fortran compiler enabled with OpenMP 3.0.  My (simplified) code is below:

```
!$omp parallel do reduction(+:f)  private(n,m,l,i,j,k, &
!$omp            parm,ista,iend,jsta,jend,ksta,kend)
do n=1,lm     !k
 do m=1,jm   !j
  do l=1,im !i

    if (val(l,m,n) .ne. zero) then

     jsta=max j bounds in box
     jend=min j bounds in box
     ista=max i bounds in box
     iend=min i bounds in box
     ksta=min k bounds in box
     kend=max k bounds in box

     do k=ksta,kend
      do j=jsta,jend
       do i=ista,iend

          parm = exp( -dx*(abs(i-l)) &
                      -dy*(abs(j-m)) &
                      -dz*(abs(k-n)))

          f(i,j,k) = f(i,j,k)+ val(l,m,n) * parm

       end do
      end do
     end do

    end if

  end do
 end do
end do
```

Where f has dimension (im,jm,lm).  Is this simply an issue of syntax?  I've been trying this out on several smaller, toy problems but I'm having trouble getting what I learn with a smaller test to apply in this context.  For reference purposes I asked a similar question a few months back but the problem has changed slightly since then and I don't believe the solution is as straightforward now ( [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257887/openmp-f90-95-nested-do-loops-problems-getting-improvement-over-serial-impleme) ).

Thanks for any help/comments!

Comment: I dont see anything wrong, so may i suggest deugging `jsta=max j bounds in box` this part?  if the array index is way of there, it might cause seg fault.  You can compile your code with -C option to enable array bound check.

Comment: it might be that you run out of stack memory. Try to use allocate() or pointers to put the fields on the heap. Maybe there are also some environment variables for your system to increase the stack. Finally, does it work for small sized problems?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions.  I'll try revisiting this issue and will let you all know if I learn anything!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Intel Fortran compiler, but I have had a similar experience like you, segmentation fault at runtime.

In my case, the following solves the problem, which increases thread stack size. I hope this helps.

```
[hoge@hoge]$ ulimit -s unlimited
[hoge@hoge]$ export OMP_STACKSIZE=1g # 1GB for thread stack size
```